# How to merge multiple text rows based on a column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I got this data:

```
Input                     userid
hello                      1001  
hi                         1002  
my name is bill            1002  
how are you?               1003  
can you help?              1003  
what is new?               1005  
hello                      1006  
about my request           1006
```

I want to group the Input rows based on the userid column:

```
Input                      userid
hello                       1001  
hi my name is bill          1002  
how are you? can you help?  1003              
what is new?                1005  
hello about my request      1006
```

Comment: `out = df.groupby("userid", as_index=False)["Input"].agg(" ".join)[df.columns]`

Comment: I get a KeyError with the list of the rest of the dataset columns. I'm trying to focus only on those two columns.

Comment: You can remove `[df.columns]`. Also, please read [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).